# What's the difference between apt full-upgrade and apt upgrade when this site says to use both commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

This [guide](https://www.vandorp.biz/2012/01/installing-a-lightweight-lxdevnc-desktop-environment-on-your-ubuntudebian-vps/#.YLbZLKEpD-j) says to use both commands before installing stuff. Is it true that I should use both commands? Both commands install packages right?

Comment: This will answer your question:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Comment: That post doesn't answer my question. If the packages are installed with dependencies using apt full-upgrade, does that mean I don't have to use apt upgrade as well?

Comment: I already know that I can use apt or apt-get for certain commands.

Comment: I posted an answer with methods I use and more information on the difference between upgrade and full-upgrade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The common difference between `upgrade` and `full-upgrade` is that a `full-upgrade` will remove the installed packages if that is needed to upgrade the whole system.

I will do a `full-upgrade` if I am intending to do a big upgrade to my Linux systems.

[Linux apt-get commands](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-apt-command/) ([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230608130200/https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-apt-command/))

> The difference between `upgrade` and `full-upgrade` is that the later will
> remove the installed packages if that is needed to upgrade the whole
> system.  **Be extra careful when using this command**

You need to use care lest you *remove* (with `full-upgrade`) packages you did not intend to be removed.

I will more frequently use *autoremove* (through `sudo apt autoremove`) to remove old packages and then just use upgrade.

It is not necessarily hard and fast.

The article I posted above is good to read through entirely.

If I need to do an aggressive cleanup or a bit of a repair before further upgrades, I will run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes however should I use both apt upgrade or apt full-upgrade or just either one or the other?

Comment: If your system is working very well, regular upgrade should work just fine. I do not see any issue with just using regular upgrade.  I actually do not see a need to use both. If you wish to clean up old installs, just use full-upgrade.

Comment: Ok thanks very much!